# Signal penetration in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The problem consists in modelling propagation of a signal (eg. light or sound etc) through a series of obstacles, as on the figure below. The signal cannot pass through bottom surface (terrain), but it can traverse obstacles. I want to count the number of obstacles traversed.

[image]

Terrain and obstacles are in 2D numpy arrays (x,y,z). This is what I do:

```
output = numpy.zeros(terrain.shape)

obstacles = terrain + obstacle_heights


for i in xrange (obstacles.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange (obstacles.shape[1]):

        mask = obstacles[i,j] > terrain[i,j:]
        output[i,j:][mask] +=1
```

The result would be something like `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4 ...]` per row.

This method works fine (provided valleys on the terrain are filled by using `numpy.maximum.accumulate`). Now, would it be possible to speed up the thing by using a vectorised solution?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you explain more in details which solution are you looking for and which are the input data? I think you are looking for the creation of lines (as linestring layers) representing the signal but, in this case, it should be necessary specifying also a direction in addition to the source format.

Comment: I'm interested in both, acoustics and light attenuation (eg. haze, smoke). For the sake of simplicity, the signal is travelling parallel to terrain (vertically) and parallel to terrain grid ( horizontally). By "signal"I mean only a simple iterator over the numpy matrix.

Comment: And what about the signals height?

Comment: Signal height is arbitrary : say 1,7 metres for human height ...  Then you can raise (temporarily) the terrain for that value ` mask = obstacles[i,j] > terrain[i,j:] + 1.7` < in my code I'm using angular size wich is obtained by dividing the heights with distances from the source -  but that is not relevant here , it seems to me (?) >

Comment: It will definitely be possible to vectorize it, the FFT can be vectorized (https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/). I am struggling to understand what obstacles.shape[0] and obstacles.shape[1] represent though.

Comment: Obstacles.shape is giving the number of rows and columns. [Numpy shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)

Comment: I don't know how large you terrain is, but performance might increase if you eliminate the for loops. Something like:

output = numpy.where((obstacles - terrain) > 0, ["True","False"])

Comment: Beyond the GIS context, is it possible to apply [z-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) algorithms to the problem? It is a common problem in 3D rending with optimization possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say above, you probably could vectorize the operation to remove the for loops and make it more efficient.

However, if you consider the problem in a slightly different way - that of thresholding - you can take advantage of the tools from [scipy ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/ndimage.html) to count the obstacles:

First, threshold your terrain data by your signal height to get a boolean array of where the signal could be, regardless of the origin.

```python
signal_reach = terrain < signal_height
```

Then you can use the [`ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) method to group discrete regions:

```python
from scipy import ndimage
signal_regions, region_count = ndimage.label(signal_reach)
```

Once this is done get the region ID(s) which match the origin cell(s) of your signal. In your case it would be the first column.

```python
import numpy as np
origin_labels = np.unique(signal_regions[:, 0]) # or whatever indexes meet the start of the signal
# ndimage lables are greater than 1, 0 is an unlabeled region
origin_labels = origin_lables[origin_lables > 0]
```

Now threshold ares where the signal intercepts the terrain + obstacles, and this time  filter out regions outside or area of interest using [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```python
area_of_interest = np.isin(signal_regions, origin_labels)
signal_intercepted = (obstacles >= signal_height) & area_of_interest
```

And a final round of `ndimage.label` gives you a count of the obstacles intercepted, because we've already filtered out areas blocked by the terrain:

```python
obstacles_hit, obstacle_count = ndimage.label(signal_intercepted)
```

There's a bit more code here, but there are two big advantages:

- No for loops means the code should be reasonably quick,
- And for calculation purposes, the signal origin can be on or many cells, anywhere on the terrain raster.

Comment: This looks like a promising approach! I will test it in January and flag it as the slution if it works.